# Event driven Fetch S3 file in Nifi

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am currently fetching an S3 file Using the FetchS3Object Processor. But it is a time-driven process and sometimes the S3 files are dumped later than expected due to which the Processor is unable to fetch the file.

Is there a way to make the processor event-driven or is there a way to make the processor run in a loop until it fetches the file?

Comment: https://www.batchiq.com/nifi-process-s3-event-notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

You have at least these options:

- define aws lambda function that sends SQS message every time new object is added to S3 bucket and then consume this event in NiFi with GetSQS processor
- use ListS3 processor that will detect every new object added to S3 bucket